# How to create Schedular on SpringBoot which invoke method

Tags: spring-boot

I have a table called JobSchedular

### JobSchedular

| JobCode | JobName | JobDescription | FunctionName | Status | RunInterval(CronEcpression) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Job001 | Notify | To Send Notification | SendNotification | ACTIVE | 0 * * * * ? |
| Job002 | Appointment | To manage appointment | ManageAppointment | ACTIVE | 0 * * * * ? |

My Requirement is to Create Schedular on SPring Boot using @Scheduled annotation
which takes list of rows from tables and call the function dynamically based on corn expression

Answer (score 0):

Now spring boot has built in support to quartz. Use this example to schedule job.
https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-quartz-scheduler-email-scheduling-example/